# Can I access the entries of the ApplicationCache manifest from a JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript, offline, offline-caching, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm working with Serviceworkers and ApplicationCache and was wondering: Can I access the [ApplicationCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/applicationCache) contents from another script?

For example I was thinking of creating a fallback manifest in case a browser did not support serviceWorker for offline caching and thought it would be nice if I could just pick the entries on the manifest for caching in the serviceworker instead of maintaining a duplicate list.

I did not find any info online on whether it was possible and console-ing around with the ApplicationCache object does not give me its contents either.

Thanks for some inputs.

Comment: You want to read the text of the manifest, or the contents of the cache?

Comment: The text of the manifest. I just realized I could just fetch the manifest file from within the serviceWorker. If that worked, parse it and viola, I have my list of assets to cache. Trying now.